# WCF net.tcp binding client occasionally throws COMMUNICATION EXCEPTION

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-data-services, nettcpbinding, net-tcp

I have created a WCF service, which is currently hosted in a console application. After logging the duration it takes for my client to call the service I realized the following;
1. Time to call service method ranges from a few milliseconds to seconds.
2. Usually when the call duration is in seconds sometimes a Communication Exception which states that 
"Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:84/myservice. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.9971997. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:84." Is thrown by some clients.

What could be causing the wide variation in call duration and also some of the exceptions.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried enabling WCF tracing and message logging? enable it and post the trace log of the request